# В тысячах рублях/рублей?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно: в тысячах рублей или в тысячах рублях? Например, "сумму следует указать в тысячах ...". Была уверена, что слово "рубли" должно быть в родительном падеже, однако Word не согласен. Поясните пожалуйста, почему.

Answer (score 1):

"Тысячах рублей", конечно. Или просто "в рублях". В первом случает слова "рубли" относится к слову "тысяча" - "тысяча рублей", а во втором - к слову "указать". А Ворд не слушайте, он мне вообще слово "голубой" подчеркивает как ошибку))))